# c factor in PageRank

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-algorithms, ni.networking-internet

In page 3 of [PageRank](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/422/1/1999-66.pdf) paper is mentioned:

> let c be a factor used for normalization
>   (so that the total rank of all web pages is constant).

What is the use of `c` and how can its value be computed?

Answer (score 5):

The point of such a factor in general is that you want to be able to calibrate the scores you get, by forcing them to be within a specific range like $[0,1]$. In particular, this factor would be computed (in principle) by getting the rank of all pages and then dividing by their sum.